# Meteor bindEnvironment: "Did not check() all arguments"

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, meteor, callback, npm

My code below throws an error on the server saying:

Exception while invoking method '/app/shipping/ship' Error: Did not check() all arguments during call to '/app/shipping/ship'

```
Meteor.methods({
  '/app/shipping/ship': function (weight, length, width, height) {
    check(weight, Number);
    check(length, Number);
    check(width, Number);
    check(height, Number);

    var async = Meteor.npmRequire('async');

    var quote = function (callback) {
      Meteor.call('/app/shipping/quote', 'DE', weight, length, width, height, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err);
        }
        else {
          callback(null, res);
        }
      });
    };

    async.waterfall([
      Meteor.bindEnvironment(quote)
    ], function(err, result) {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
});
```

I think that I've checked all the arguments (weight, length, width and height), do I have to check somewhere else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[audit-argument-checks](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/auditargumentchecks) works by examining all of the arguments which are *passed* to a method, rather than the *defined* arguments. The most likely cause of your problem is that somewhere in your code you are calling the method with **greater than four arguments**, e.g.:

```
Meteor.call('/app/shipping/ship', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into that. Right now, checking again inside the Meteor.call() callback fixed the problem.